# Simplification of \begin{equation} P(Z<\theta)=P(\sum_{i=1}^{m}(\max\{\log(a+cX_i),\log(a+cY_i)\})<\Theta). \end{equation}

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X_i$ and $Y_i$ two  random variables with parameter $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$.

Let $m>0,c,b$ a positive numbers.
We define $Z$ a random variable by

$$
Z= \sum_{i=0}^{m}(\max\{\log(a+cX_i),\log(a+cY_i)\})
$$

I would like to compute the probability

$$
P(Z<\theta)=P(\sum_{i=1}^{m}(\max\{\log(a+cX_i),\log(a+cY_i)\})<\Theta).
$$
Can simplify to
$$
P(Z<\theta)=P(\sum_{i=1}^{m}\log(\max\{(a+cX_i),(a+cY_i)\})<\Theta).
$$
$$
P(Z<\theta)=P(\log(\prod_{i=1}^{m}\max\{(a+cX_i),(a+cY_i)\})<\Theta).
$$
$$
P(Z<\theta)=P((\prod_{i=1}^{m}\max\{(a+cX_i),(a+cY_i)\})<e^{\Theta}).
$$
Does this simplification possible.

Comment: Yes it looks fine. The first step uses the strictly increasing property of log, and the last two steps are just elementary log properties.

Comment: ok Thanks for information